# How do I create a time series with missing data?

Tags: r

I am creating a time plot in R for Wal-Mart stock prices but there are some days missing. For example,

```
4   02/08/01 52.30

5   02/09/01 50.40

6   02/12/01 53.45

7   02/13/01 54.10

8   02/14/01 53.00

9   02/15/01 52.00
```

However, R fills in the missing days with the prices that I do have:

```
4   02/08/01 52.30

5   02/09/01 50.40

6   02/10/01 53.45

7   02/11/01 54.10

8   02/12/01 53.00

9   02/13/01 52.00
```

How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
walmart <- read.csv("/Users/Penny/Desktop/Spring 2017/SS/Group HW/WalMartStock.csv", header=T)

stock.ts <- ts(walmart$Close, frequency = 365, start = c(2001,2), end = c(2002,2))

plot(stock.ts, main = "Wal-Mart Stock", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Closing Price", ylim = c(40,60), bty = "l")
```

Comment: Take a look at `xts` as an alternative to `ts` when you have an irregular time series (i.e., one where observation does not occur at regular intervals).

Comment: Ts is used only for regular frequency data. Ulfelder option is your best bet. Look into xts.